# C# foreach loop if item does not exists skip it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a loop like so:

```
@foreach(var elevation in inventory.Elevations)
{
     <td>@elevation.Title</td>
}
```

Now my inventory.Elevations could have either 3 or 4 items, never more or less.

And the title can either be "A", "B", "C" or "D". For an example one inventory.Elevations could have A, C & D but not B while another could have B, C, D but not A, while another could have A, B, D but not C. If that is the case I would like to display `<td>&nbsp;</td>` How would I accomplish this? I wouldnt even know what to try to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you have all the list of items that could be present in the inventory

Comment: No I do not, some inventory could have A, B, C but not D while some could have A, B, C & D...does that make sense?

Comment: If your elevations are B,C,D. Then how should it display? `<td>@elevation.Title</td><td>@elevation.Title</td><td>@elevation.Title</td><td>&nbsp;</td>`? Or `<td>&nbsp;</td><td>@elevation.Title</td><td>@elevation.Title</td><td>@elevation.Title</td>`?

Comment: If something is in an array, how can it not exist? Or are you saying it's not in the array but it could/should be?

Comment: @Karan if the elevations are A, C, D then it should display like so: `<td>@elevation.Title</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>@elevation.Title</td><td>@elevation.Title</td>`

Comment: Are these titles same or will be different for each object?

Comment: @PramilGawande the title can either be A, B, C or D....some objects may only have 3 of these or all 4. The titles are always either A, B, C or D

Comment: I think @Karan has already answered your question.
You can try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your all elevations in one list as `var elevations = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };`. Loop over each one and check in your `inventory.Elevations`. If found then get `Title` else `&nbsp;`. Complete code is like below.

```
@{
    // Set all your elevations
    var elevations = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
}

@foreach(var e in elevations)
{
    <td>@(inventory.Elevations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == e)?.Title ?? "&nbsp;")</td>
}
```

Or you can add ternary with condition `elevations.Contains` like below.

```
@{
    // Set all your elevations
    var elevations = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
}

@foreach(var elevation in inventory.Elevations)
{
    <td>@(elevations.Contains(elevation.Title) ? elevation.Title : "&nbsp;")</td>
}
```